# Reboot Windows Computer using Putty (SSH)

Tags: ssh, putty, reboot, ssh-tunnel

I am running Putty and am able to SSH into a network (Tomato is running the SSH server). How can I reboot a Windows computer on the network from Putty? What command do I type?

Comment: What do you mean by "SSH into a network"?

Comment: I'm probably not using the right terminology. I mean that I have a router running an SSH server, and then remotely I use Putty to connect to that SSH server. What command would I type in Putty to reboot a Windows computer on that network? I know I can type "reboot" to reboot the router (which is running the SSH server), but I don't want to do that. I want to reboot a computer. I know the computer's IP address, and the Administrator username and password.

Comment: `net rpc shutdown -r  -I IPADDRESS -U USERNAME%PASSWORD`

Comment: When I try that, I get the error "-sh: net: not found"

Comment: it is part of samba-common-bin (in Debian, you didn't say which distro is your's) so the package has to be installed.